# Array Tree reading

Tags: arrays, function, recursion, tree

I have this array that I want to read:

```
Tree [ "my",
       [ "name",
         [ "is",
           [ "Toto" ],
           [ "Bob"  ]
         ]
       ],
       [ "algo",
         [ "doesn't",
           [ "work" ]
         ],
         [ "fail" ]
       ]
     ]
```

This should give my 4 sentences:

- My name is Toto
- My name is Bob
- My algo doesn't work
- My algo fail

But my recursive try doesn't success ...
Thank you.

Comment: What language are you working in?

Comment: Looks like you lost **]** before **[ "algo",** and **,** after **[ "Toto"]**

Comment: I edit. Thank.

I use php. But pseudo code is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your structure is like that:

```
node = [first, second]
first = string
second = [node, node, ...] or [string, string, ...]
```

Your pseudocode will be like this:

```
struct node {string first; object second }

parse(string s, node tree)
{
    if (node.second is string)               //leaf of tree
        print(s + " " + node.second);
    else                                    //go deeper for each branch
        for each (b in node.second)
            parse(s + node.first, b);
}

main()
{
   parse(root.first, root.second);
}
```

Comment: My struct is more like:
`node = Array(String[, [node, [node, [...]]]])`
where [] means not mandatory.

Comment: I wrote the same: any _second_ can be either _node_ or _string_. _node_ means deep recursion, _string_ means end of sentence

Comment: Ok, but I read it like: second is an array of node or a string. Which not fit my case. Btw I'm testing with an adaptation of you'r recursive function and see if it's fit.

Comment: Solution adapt from Yarg function: http://pastebin.com/uJtZwj1R

Answer (score 0):

In perl:

```
sub act {
    my $data = shift;
    my $cb = shift;
    my @sentence = ();
    my $p;
    $p = sub{
            my $n = shift;
            if(defined $n && ref $n eq 'ARRAY'){
                    foreach my $item (@{$n}){
                            $p->($item);
                    }
                    if($#{$n} == 0){
                            &{$cb}(@sentence);
                    }
                    pop @sentence;
            } else{
                    push(@sentence, $n);
            }
    };
    $p->($data);
}

act($tree, sub {print join ' ', @_,"\n";});
```

But it's essentially the same as what you figured out.